# How to say "twelve tigers"

Tags: vocabulary

I learned that two tigers is said "两只老虎" but I wonder how to say 
twelve tigers, twenty two tigers in Chinese.
Is that 十二只老虎 and 二十二只老虎  or 十两只老虎 and 二十两只老虎

Comment: Should be 十二只老虎 and 二十二只老虎.

Answer (score 6):

As @songyuanyao says `十二只老虎` and `二十二只老虎` are correct.

You cannot use `兩` here unless you literally meant to say "12 *ounces* of tiger (meat?)". The reason is that **`兩` actually means "*one pair*".** That is, `两只老虎` is "*a pair of tigers*". Notice that it is specifically ***one*** pair; which means you cannot use `二十两` to mean "twenty pairs" either.

Now, `兩` does get used in bigger numbers. But that's only strictly for **two of** something". For example:

- 一千兩百 - "*One thousand and **two** hundred*"
- 兩百 - "***two*** hundred"
- 兩百兆 - "***two*** hundred trillion"

In these cases, you are saying "**a pair** of one hundred", regardless of the rest of the number. This works because 100 is a named number in Chinese (as it is in English). The other numbers this works for are:

- 千 - thousand
- 萬 - ten thousand
- 億 - hundred million
- 兆 - trillion / million
- ...and other ridiculously large numbers that you'll likely never ever encounter.